# JMeter distributed test with multiple Sampler Sender modes

Tags: testing, jmeter, distributed

I'm trying to run a distributed test with JMeter 2.9 with:

- **1 client** (master JMeter to start test and collect results)
- **2 servers** (slaves that execute the actual requests and send data back to client)

The question is about the **sampler sender mode** configuration: I want to use **DiskStore** to store results in each slave and collect them after test is over. I've already tested this successfully.

But I would like to have some data **during the execution** to see how the test is going, before the end of it.

My first attempt was to configure `sample_sender_client_configured=false` which is supposed to  force the use of slave configuration. And then configure one slave with DiskStore and the other with **Standard** mode. I understood that with this configuration slave in Standard would send data to master **during the test** and slave with DiskStore would send data **after the test** was finished.

During the execution though, no data was shown in listeners. And when the test finished results where plotted correctly (from both slaves I assume).

Any ideas on how to approach this issue? is it possible to have **mutiple sample sender modes in distributed testing**? is there any other option to have a DiskStore mode for distributed testing and still have some data during the test?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mix modes.
Last 2.9 version ships with optimal config.

To have results during test add this to user.properties in client:

```
 summariser.name=summary 
 # 
  # interval between summaries (in seconds) default 3 minutes 
  summary.interval=20 
  # 
  # Write messages to log file 
  summariser.log=false 
  # 
  # Write messages to System.out 
  summariser.out=true
```

Comment: Using this configuration I can't manage to get summary results in GUI mode. I understand that I could have DiskMode for sample sending mode on slaves, and the summariser (is it configured on master or does it need config on each slave?) so that I get data for the listeners in Master (GUI mode) each 20 secs (or any other interval). Is that correct? If so, is there any other configuration step to have results shown on listeners?

Comment: Summary is in NON GUI mode which is what you should use during LOAD Tests, read this:http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/

Comment: My idea is to use NON GUI mode. But I was wondering if there is any option to have information during the test. If you run a lenghty test and something goes wrong during it, without any feedback you end up waiting always for the end of the it. Or am I missing something and there is no point in caring about the test until the end? isn't it useful to be able to stop if something is wrong and save time by re-running when possible? By the way, I took a first glance at the article and I find it very interesting, thank you very much for the info PMD.

Comment: My mistake. I didn't realize that summariser (as you suggested) already provides data to console (and log if needed) which is enough to have an idea on how the test is going. I was stubbornly trying to get info in GUI mode. I'll follow your recommendation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I added this config to user.properties file but did not see sumary of results beig printed on console. I am also using `mode=DiskStore` though did not see results being written jtl file on client after test run is over :-/